# Cannot Save New Records in PgAdmin4- "SAVE" Icon Grayed Out

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm saving new record entries in PgAdmin4 database, but cannot saved the new records because the "SAVE" icon is grayed out. What should I do to enable the SAVE function?

I'm just learning the PostgreSQL database and PgAdmin4 on the creation of database by following a tutorial in YouTube. As a result, I'm stuck on the "saving step" and don't know what to do. I've googled out for a solution and checked a similar issue here at stack overflow, but cannot find one.

There is no coding involved in my issue.

I did not get any error messages. It's simply that the "SAVE" function is grayed out and am not able to commit my new record entries to the new database I created.

Answer (score 38):

I encountered the same issue. It seems that the PgAdmin UI was changed, and now there is this "Save Data Changes" button:

[image: Save changes button]

This worked for me.

Comment: hey tysm this worked for me! I was watching an older video and it doesn't work for some reason. Which is odd because why would you put it there in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

The save icon in UI keeps changing, this is the one I see on my mac to save data.
[image]

Comment: On WIndows with pgAdmin 4 v5.7, looks the same as Puneet's.

Answer (score 1):

In pgAdmin 4 to save the changes `f6` is the shortcut or you can click on the below icon to save the changes done in the table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For other pgAdmin 4 newbies (like me) watching an old video, another notable UI change is the Execute/Refresh button: was a lightening bolt, now a play button.

Video:
[image]

In pgAdmin 4 v5.7:
[image]